# Numba lowering error when reassigning 'next' link of a linked-list element

Tags: python, numba

The following code is my implementation of a linked list using numba (related examples can be seen [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/linkedlist.py), [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/stack.py) and [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/examples/binarytree.py)).
The `remove` function removes the element at position `index`.
(Notice that it is here assumed that `index` will always be a valid position)
To remove such element (`index`) we do an assignment like `element[index-1].next -> element[index+1]`. But numba does not seem to like when I do that:

```py
from numba import deferred_type,optional
from numba import int64
from numba import jitclass,njit

list_type = deferred_type()

spec = [
    ('data',int64),
    ('next',optional(list_type))
]
@jitclass(spec)
class List(object):
    def __init__(self,data,next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def prepend(self, data):
        return List(data, self)

list_type.define(List.class_type.instance_type)

def length(stack):
    i = 0
    while stack is not None:
        stack = stack.next
        i+=1
    return i

@njit
def remove(stack,index):
    prev = None
    if index == 0:
        stack = stack.next
    else:
        cur = stack
        i = 0
        while cur is not None:
            if index == i:
                break
            i = i+1
            prev = cur
            cur = cur.next
        prev.next = cur.next
    return stack

def runme():
    from numpy.random import randint
    a = randint(0,100,10)

    list_ = None

    for n in a:
        if list_ is None:
            list_ = List(n,None)
        else:
            list_ = list_.prepend(n)
    print(length(list_))

    indexes = list(range(len(a)))
    for i in indexes[::-1]:
        list_ = remove(list_,i)
    print(length(list_))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runme()
```

It breaks at line `prev.next = cur.next` with the following error:

```
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
No definition for lowering ?instance.jitclass.List#14bebc8<data:int64,next:?DeferredType#140432587762264>.next = ?DeferredType#140432587762264
File "numba_test.py", line 43
[1] During: lowering "(prev).next = $70.2" at numba_test.py (43)
```

It looks like `prev.next` cannot be reassigned, but I'm not really sure what is going on here.

I am using **numba 0.35.0** and **python 3.6.2**.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

Current status

The error is a bug in Numba. For more info, go to the corresponding issue: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2606

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `nopython` mode does support this feature. Just use the "normal" `jit` decorator. This falls back to plain Python if needed:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def remove(stack,index):
    prev = None
    if index == 0:
        stack = stack.next
    else:
        cur = stack
        i = 0
        while cur is not None:
            if index == i:
                break
            i = i+1
            prev = cur
            cur = cur.next
        prev.next = cur.next
    return stack
```

Because `njit` is equivalent to `jit(nopython=True)`.

Test output:

```
10
0
```

Comment: It runs, yes. But actually slower than pure python (no @jit). If you `timeit`, the decorated version with `@jit` does in ~180us, while pure python does in ~80us.

Comment: Looks more  like use case for PyPy to me.

Comment: Hi Mike, just to give you an update. There is an issue to handle the error here in question: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2606 . thanks